# Extracting key-value pairs from a string using ruby & regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to accomplish the following with ruby and if possible a regex:

Input: `"something {\"key\":\"value\",\"key2\":3}"`
Output: `[["\"key\"", "\"value\""], [["\"key2\"", "3"]]`

My attempt so far:

```rb
s = "something {key:\"value\",key2:3}"
s.scan(/.* {(?:([^:]+):([^,}]+),?)+}$/)

# Output: [["\"key2\"", "3"]]
```

For some reason the regex above only matches the last key value pair. Does someone know how to retrieve all the pairs?

Just to be clear, "something" can be any kind of string. For this reason, solutions such as (1) splitting the text directly on the equal or (2) a regex as used in `s.scan(/(?:([^:]+):([^,}]+),?)/)` don't work for me.

I know there are similar questions on SO. Still, from what I saw, they mostly tend towards the solutions 1 & 2 or focus on a single key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

your string looks like a json data structure encoded as a string, you can use JSON.parse for this as long as you remove the word "something " from the string

```
require 'json'

string = "something {\"key\":\"value\",\"key2\":3}"
# the following line removes the word something 
string = string[string.index("{")..-1]
x = JSON.parse(string)
puts x["key"]
puts x["key2"]
```

you can then convert that to an array if required

alternatively if you want to use regular expressions try

```
string.scan(/(?:"(\w+)":"?(\w+)"?)/)
```

Comment: Hi @SomeonRandom3142, the string is not a valid JSON so I cannot work with the json library. Also, the "something" can be any string of characters including "{}:\"". So something like "\"hey\":ho {\"key\":\"value\",\"key2\":3}" is possible.